# Airflow FTPS Hook with Certificate/Key

Tags: python, certificate, airflow, key, ftps

good evening!

I am having some issues connecting to an external FTPS server using Airflow's [FTPS Hook](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-ftp/stable/_modules/airflow/providers/ftp/hooks/ftp.html#FTPSHook).

Here's a condensed version of my function which runs in a python operator:

```
def ftps_connection_test(conn_id, source_path, 
                source_connection_type):

    if source_connection_type == 'FTPS':

        ftps_hook=FTPSHook(ftp_conn_id=conn_id)
        ftps_hook.get_conn().prot_p()

        print('Testing Connection:', ftps_hook.test_connection())
```

I am getting a handshake error when running the DAG because I need to provide a certificate file when connecting. If I try connecting in WinSCP without this certificate file I get a very similar error.

I've been fiddling with this for a day but I couldn't figure out how to create a connection with a key/cert file using this hook.

Would someone know how to resolve this?

Many thanks in advance!

Tried searching online for similar errors
Tried searching through Airflow's Docs

Answer (score 1):

The way I got it to work was modifying the FTPS Operator Airflow provides and importing that instead:

Here's my version of the FTPSHook that takes in a `keyfile` and a `certfile`:

```
from airflow.providers.ftp.hooks.ftp import FTPHook
import ftplib

class FTPSCustomHook(FTPHook):
    """Base Airflow hook modified by @vitor.aranha to work over explicit TLS with keyfile and certfile authentication"""

    def get_conn(self) -> ftplib.FTP:
        """Returns a FTPS connection object."""
        if self.conn is None:
            params = self.get_connection(self.ftp_conn_id)
            pasv = params.extra_dejson.get("passive", True)

            if params.port:
                ftplib.FTP_TLS.port = params.port

            self.conn = ftplib.FTP_TLS(params.host, 
                                       params.login, 
                                       params.password, 
                                       certfile=params.extra_dejson['certfile_path'],
                                       keyfile=params.extra_dejson['keyfile_path'])
            self.conn.set_pasv(pasv)
            self.conn.prot_p()

        return self.conn
```

in order for this to work the keyfile and certfile paths must be specified in the connection extras in the airflow UI.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It seems the default hook uses FTP [FTP](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP) class which does not support TLS support. Source code [here](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/providers/ftp/hooks/ftp.py#L62). I think you need the connection of class [FTP_TLS](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP_TLS). So either you have to manipulate the connection hook or I'd recommend writing a new hook using the other class and passing the certificate and other details as parameters.

Comment: OP needs not only TLS, but also to authenticate with a certificate.

Comment: Thank you! That was indeed the approach I took! I will leave my custom class here for future reference.